# Is $\;F =\{∅, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$ a $\;\sigma$-algebra of $\;\{1, 2, 3\}?$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I think that it is not a $\sigma$-algebra of $\{1, 2, 3\},$ because  for example

- $\{1, 2\} \cap \{1, 3\} = \{1\}$
- $\{1, 3\} \cap \{2, 3\} = \{3\}$
- $\{1, 2\}' = \{3\},$ etc.

which are not elements in $F.$ However, I'm not sure if this is right, because I'm not sure if I understand what a $\sigma$-algebra is; I haven't heard it explained thoroughly.

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra needs to be closed for finite intersections, so $F$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @PEJ you understand it properly. Each of three examples that you give suffices to prove that  it is not a sigma algebra.

Comment: Alright, that's good to know. Thank you guys for your feedback.